# Adobe PDF Printing - Printing multiple files with the same name

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat, print-to-pdf

I have an application that prints out multiple pages as separate documents (because they are separate documents) as a batch process. However, the program always names the file the same, so when I pass it through the Adobe PDF printer (Adobe 9 Standard), the printer just overwrites the file continuously so all I have is the last file printed.

Is it possible to make Adobe apply some sort of suffix (like document (1).pdf, I don't care) to files printed in this way? The files will be going through an OCR rename process after so the filename doesn't matter.

I can't use the "ask me" method because the program prints 10+ documents all at once and it would be too cumbersome to rename manually. I'm also not against different software for this purpose.

Comment: Are you stuck with the Adobe PDF printer - there are quite a few alternatives which may do what you need?

Comment: @Dan I'm not. I've tried PDFCreator (free version of novaPDF) which didn't work...seemed to "skip" files randomly with no reasoning. goPDF refused to work on a terminal server which is a requirement.

Comment: Would creating one PDF, and then braking it up using Acrobat be an option for your workflow?

Comment: @MaxWyss Unfortunately not. The program generates the PDFs itself and there's no way to control it.

Comment: One possible solution would be turning the directory the PDF ends up in into an observed folder, and have a very short interval (less than the interval form the application producing the PDFs), of a process to rename the files, in the sense already suggested. Another possibility might be intercepting the printing queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple batch file to rename the PDFs on the fly. For example:

```
Set file_nr=1
:Startloop
If not exist c:\mydir\document.pdf goto wait1sec
ren c:\mydir\document.pdf c:\mydir\document%file_nr%.pdf
Set /a file_nr+=1
:wait1sec
:: delay 1 sec (1000 ms) by pinging a non-existent IP address once
ping 1.2.3.4 /n 1 /w 1000
goto Startloop
```

Comment: i gave this a try...it's not quite fast enough.

Comment: What if you reduce the delay time, say to 100?

Answer (score 0):

[Commercial solution](http://www.printandshare.info): set the PDF file output options to "Create a unique file name" and it ads 00001 to it. etc..

[image: Print&Share PDF file output options]